# Websockets message delivery when mobile app is in the background

Tags: ios, websocket, pubnub, pusher

I am trying to implement an iOS chat application using Pusher or PubNub (websockets).

Question: **How does message delivery work when the iOS app is in the background?**

I understand that Websockets implementations provide real-time messaging and don't cache the messages. **Is the message lost because the socket connection is broken when the app is in the background?**

If yes, how do I recover the lost messages? One idea is to implement a state refresh protocol every time the app comes to foreground.

Answer (score 2):

## PubNub Missed Message Recovery Options

You mentioned PubNub (the company I work for) and as @FrankG mentioned, unless you have permission from Apple to run your app in background (staying connected to internet, and therefore, PubNub), you will not receive any message in realtime.

You can use [PubNub's Mobile Push Gateway](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/ios-objective-c/mobile-gateway-sdk-v4) and receive APNS push messages while you app is in background (but idle/not running) or completely not running (kill state).

When the app is activated again, PubNub can be [configured to automatically retrieve missed messages](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/ios-objective-c/api-reference-sdk-v4#subscribe) from the channel(s) it was subscribed to, but this is good for short periods of disconnection.

For longer periods being offline, you can enable [Storage & Playback](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/ios-objective-c/storage-and-history-sdk-v4) and use [the `historyForChannel` API to fetch all the missed messages](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/ios-objective-c/api-reference-sdk-v4#history) of all channels you require.

Answer (score 1):

Answer:  It doesn't.

If the iOS app is in the background, you are out of luck.  There is no official (and Apple sanctioned) way of keeping a connection open when the app is in the background.  There are hacks like playing a silent audio track to keep it in the foreground, but Apple doesn't approve of such hacks.  You'll need to use APNS to send an offline message to bring the app to the foreground so it can reconnect.

And you are 100% correct that the WS standard does not address caching.  That has to be performed by another subsystem in your architecture.

The Kaazing Gateway (disclosure: the company I work for) has a feature in our messaging Gateway that caches the last value sent.  When the client reconnects (our client libs auto-reconnect), they will see that value.